# Catch a Wifi Authentication on Windows Mobile with C#

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-mobile, .net-cf-3.5, intermec

I would like to know if can be possible to catch a wifi authentication on windows mobile and use in NetworkCredential at my app based on windows form and c#.

My client want this feature because I put one login from app and has one another login to wifi connnectio.

More details: I working on Intermec CN3 with Windows Mobile 6.1 and .NET Compact Framework 3.5.

Can suggest something?

Comment: You want to capture what exactly? The authentication data for the wifi connection. I am pretty sure that is a horrible idea one that Microsoft does not allow an application to do.  Explain the following sentence **My client want this feature because I put one login from app and has one another login to wifi connnectio.** because it makes no sense.

Comment: Ramhound, the handheld need stay at domain to access web services to send and receive some informations and I need to catch the credential of wifi authentication to avoid one of the login and put only one. I got to be clear?

Comment: Why don't you simply use the active internet connection on the phone?  If the phone is connected then it should be part of the domain.  You still have not made the bold text clear.

Comment: Ramhound, now my app has a login and the handheld has another login to connect at wifi. And my client need that one from two logins can been removed to facility the final user because the instability's wifi.

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me. I have not found a way to do this, however. Nothing I've found seems to expose those properties.